# Can I slaughter young animals for full rewards?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Does butchering non-adult tame animals give the same amount of meat, skin, etc. as a grown animal of the same kind?

Comment: Nice question, but an even better title.

Comment: @Wipqozn Good titles are so easy with DF...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you will receive less resources for slaughtering animals before they are fully grown.

My advice would be to check the [wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Creature) which has details about the resources gained from slaughtering animals to decide whether it is worth it or not.

It is also worth considering how much grazing space each animal needs (because animals that die of starvation cannot be slaughtered), and if you have a breeding pair of animals.

As a general rule, the amount of meat, fat, and bones received from slaughtering animals tend to vary the most between slaughtering fully grown and young animals. Other items, such as brain, heart, lungs, raw hide, etc. tend to remain constant.

Comment: I think they'd always remain constant since you never grow more brains...right?

Comment: We'll, this is dwarf fortress. You can get more than one brain when slaughtering some creatures, such as forgotten beasts, but that doesn't really apply here as you don't encounter young versions of those creatures.